# Pourquoi n'y a-t-il pas de contraire de "cher" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie, adjectifs, histoire

Pourquoi le français n'a-t-il pas de mot courant pour exprimer le **contraire de *"cher"*** (au sens pécuniaire) ?

En pratique la tournure *"peu/pas cher"* semble être la plus courante, et les dictionnaires mentionnent en général le mot composé *"bon marché"*. Je suis étonné qu'au lieu d'un adjectif (non composé) l'usage pour exprimer ce sens soit une négation.

Anglais, allemand et espagnol, qui sont des langues géographiquement voisines du français, possèdent pourtant un adjectif pour *"cher"* et un adjectif pour son contraire (*cheap*, *billig*, *barato*). Le latin possède le mot *"vilis"*, qui a d'ailleurs donné *"vil"* en français. L'italien par contre ne semble pas avoir de tel mot non plus, utilisant apparemment comme en français la tournure *"bon marché"*.

Quelle est la raison ? Un adjectif a-t-il existé puis disparu ? Ou a-t-il changé de signification, laissant la langue sans mot pour exprimer ce sens ?

---

Je n'ai toujours pas trouvé d'explication faisant autorité, mais en regardant du côté de *"vil"* il y a peut-être une piste.

Le [Trésor de la langue française dit à propos de son étymologie](http://cnrtl.fr/etymologie/vil) :

> « Qui est de peu de valeur ou sans valeur. »

[Wiktionaire dit également](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vil) :

> (vieilli) « Qui est de peu de valeur, de prix bas: »

L'un comme l'autre donnent l'exemple :

> « à vil prix »

Il est tentant de penser que *"vil"* voulait effectivement dire *"pas cher"* à l'origine, puis que son sens est devenu péjoratif, au point de faire disparaître son usage au sens neutre.

Quelqu'un peut-il confirmer ou infirmer cette hypothèse ?

Comment: Merci pour cette question! Je me la suis souvent posée mais n'avait pas encore pensé à la soumettre ici. Comment un élément aussi utile et courant n'a-t-il pas un mot simple, clair et attribué!?

Comment: Il n'y a pas qu'en français .
En néerlandais aussi : goedkoop calqué directement du français, avec les comparatifs et superlatifs allant dans le même sens meilleur marché : goedkoper ( parfois beterkoop ) et le meilleur marché : het goedkoopst...etc

Comment: Attention au "cheap" anglais, qui signifie aussi "de mauvaise qualité" ; le patron d'une grande chaîne de distribution a récemment fait afficher "XYZ does not sell cheap food". Cela a fait les gros titres de la presse, ironique, dès le lendemain, et les ventes ont baissé ...

Comment: C'est vrai, *"inexpensive"* est plus neutre. Je laisse tout de même *"cheap"* qui a clairement une origine propre et n'est pas juste un adjectif avec un préfixe de négation.

Comment: @JulienGuertault :  Le Dictionnaire historique de la langue française (sld A. Rey) confirme : Vil est issu (1080) du latin classique vilis « bon marché », d'où « de peu de valeur » au propre et au figuré, ce mot latin est sans origine connu. Appliqué aux choses le sens latin de « sans valeur » est sorti d'usage sauf dans la locution « à vil prix » (1518).

Comment: @Laure: il faut que ce soit une réponse pour que je puisse l'accepter ! :)

Comment: @JulienGuertault : Je n'ai mis une réponse qu'après moultes hésitations ; en effet, je n'apporte aucun élément de réponse, une simple confirmation de ton hypothèse. Mettre une réponse pour si peu fait un peu « course aux points », ce qui n'est pas pourquoi je fréquente EL&U (et d'autres forums de StackExchange !)

Comment: C'est comme "peu profond", il n'y a pas terme en Français. (En anglais il s'agit de "shallow")

Comment: @Laure : je comprends, mais ta réponse apporte au contraire un élément tangible : une information sur l'historique de "vil" supportée par une citation d'un ouvrage.

Comment: @JeromeJ : ah oui tiens. Il y a bien "superficiel", mais ça ne marche que dans un contexte particulier.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tu cites quasiment la réponse dans ta question. Le mot latin *[vilis](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vilis)* avait déjà le double sens de « de peu de valeur marchande » (c'est-à-dire pas cher) et de « de peu de valeur morale » (c'est-à-dire vulgaire, méprisable, mauvais). C'est le sens moral (sous diverses nuances) qui s'est imposé dans la plupart des langues romanes : français, italien, espagnol, portugais. Ces langues ont trouvé d'autres mots pour signifier « pas cher » : *[economico](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/economico#Italian)* en italien ; *[barato](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barato#Spanish)* en espagnol et en portugais (littérallement « que l'on peut troquer », « marchandable », ce qui n'est pas si loin du français *bon marché*) ; *[ieftin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ieftin#Romanian)* en roumain (emprunté au bulgare).

Le [*Dictionnaire du moyen français*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/vil?idf=dmfXgXrmXvcjh;str=0) cite les deux sens mais fait la part belle au sens moral : « de peu d'importance », « repoussant », « roturier », « méprisable ». Le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française* mentionne les deux sens dans sa [4<sup>e</sup> édition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie4/vil), mais limite le sens de « bon marché » à l'expression *vil prix*.

Comment: Merci pour l'explication !

Comment: Tu parles le portugais . . .?

Comment: @Aerovistae Não, por quê?

Comment: D'ailleurs "éco" finira peut-être par passer dans le langage courant

Answer (score 12):

"Cher", pour une marchandise ou un service, a une idée d'excès.

L'opposé ne me semble donc pas devoir être recherché dans une insuffisance, mais dans l'absence d'excès, exprimée par :

juste, justifié(e), équitable, raisonnable, modique.

Answer (score 8):

Il existe bel et bien un mot : **[abordable](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/abordable)**.

Comment: Cette salade est *abordable*, ouf !

Comment: Il y a quand même une nuance : *abordable* signifie non-cher (incluant les prix moyens), alors que *bon marché* signifie le contraire de cher (excluant les prix moyens).

Comment: Je suis d'accord, @Gilles. C'est donc effectivement le contraire de *cher*, mais pas un synonyme de *bon marché*.

Comment: Non avec ce raisonnement c'est la négation de *cher* et pas son contraire !

Answer (score 6):

**Il y a des mots très employés**, sans ambiguité pour s'opposer à *cher* qui sont:

- abordable
- économique
- bradé
- donné

Et bien sûr l'expression *bon marché*.

Les nuances et les frontières entre prix *pas cher, peu cher, moyennement cher, cher, très cher* sont assez difficiles à fixer (tout cela est subjectif):

- *abordable* peut inclure les prix moyens comme soulevé dans des commentaires (mais pas nécessairement),
- *économique* va moins haut,
- *bon marché* peu être considéré comme plus bas,
- *bradé* va plus bas (à prix cassé), même plus bas que *bon marché*, mais inclut une notion éphémère,
- *donné* est peut-être encore plus fort (plus bas).

Answer (score 4):

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sld A. Rey) confirme : **Vil** est issu (1080) du latin classique *vilis* « bon marché », d'où « de peu de valeur » au propre et au figuré, ce mot latin est sans origine connue. Appliqué aux choses le sens latin de sans valeur est sorti d'usage sauf dans la locution **à vil prix**  (1518).

Answer (score 0):

N'ayant pas en tête les mots anciens, ceux utilisés actuellement seraient :

S'il n'y a pas de réponse générique en dehors de *bon marché*, certains mots ou expressions sont synonymes et précisent souvent le contexte ou l'origine de *pas cher* :

> - je voyage en classe économique
> - j'ai acheté un objet en solde
> - je l'ai eu au rabais
> - les droits d'entrée sont insignifiants

- Dans le monde de la *[phynance](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/phynance)* ce qui n'est pas *cher* est *dévalorisé*, *déprécié* :

  > Les marchés financiers *dévaluent* ce qu'ils ont surcoté.
  >
  > Les appartements ont été *dépréciés* après la bulle financière de l'immobilier.
- *Cher*, pris dans son sens commercial (plus que pécuniaire) a pour argument contraire *donné* :

  > ... pour ce prix là, monsieur, c'est *donné* !
- Contre une vie *chère*, pour une vie *économe*.

Comment: *Donné* n'est clairement pas ce que Julien recherche, ça ne fonctionne que dans des tournures très particulières. « *J'ai pris un vol donné pour Paris hier.* », c'est incompréhensible (en tout cas ça ne résultera pas en le sens recherché). Le reste n'a rien à voir avec la question…

Comment: Note: *économique* conviendrait ici, mais ça ne change rien à la question. Pourquoi devoir utiliser un sens voisin pour exprimer « pas cher » ?

Answer (score 0):

Il existe un antonyme de cher, mais il comporte une connotation légèrement excessive:

"**dérisoire**".

Comment: Dérisoire se dit du prix en soi : "un prix dérisoire" ou "d'un coût dérisoire". mais ce n'est pas l'équivalent de cheap. "A cheap car" ne saurait être traduite en "une voiture dérisoire".